# Find all $n$ natural numbers such that : $n^{2}-3$ divisible by a perfect square $m>1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, square-numbers

Problem :

Find all $n$ natural numbers such that : $k=n^{2}-3$ divisible by a perfect square $m>1$

I'm going to find the smallest number then find all this numbers

I was tired many time of $n$

$n=2$ so $k=1$ $×$

$n=3$ so $k=6$ $×$

$n=4$ so $k=13$ $×$

$n=5$ so $k=22$ $×$

$n=6$ so $k=33$ $×$

.
 .
 .

I don't know which number must be try it ?

And how I find all this numbers $n=?$

Comment: The $n$ less than $1000$ are $27,61,94,108,148,215,223,230,256,267,269,270,277,306,336,390,399,446,457,511,540,568,578,615,632,699,737,752,753,784,820,829,835,874,906,941,945,953,955,995$

Answer (score 2):

$$(22+5)^2-3=22^2+220+25-3\equiv -22+22\pmod{121}$$
$$(65-4)^2-3=65^2-520+16-3\equiv-13+13\pmod{169}$$
Finding all solutions requires at least a somewhat advanced theorem, namely the law of quadratic reciprocity.

For example, there are infinitely many $n^2-3$ that are multiple of $13^2$ or $23^2$, but none that is multiple of $17^2$ or $29^2$.

If $p>3$, $n^2-3$ can be a multiple of $p^2$ iff $p\equiv \pm1\pmod {12}$. For $p=2,3$, it is not possible.

Comment: This does not give all solutions, as $61^2-3=13^2\times 22$ There are other possible values for $m$, but aside from finding a few examples, I have no idea how to solve this

Comment: As the [Properties of the Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol#Properties_of_the_Legendre_symbol) section of Wikipedia's "Legendre symbol" article states, for an odd prime $p \neq 3$, $3$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ only if $p \equiv 1 \; \text{ or } \; 11 \pmod{12}$. In particular, it means (and it's explicitly stated) that $p \equiv 7 \pmod{12}$ is *not* allowed. Also, obviously for $p^2$, it must also be that $p \equiv 1 \text{ or } 11 \pmod{12}$, e.g., $11^2 = 121$ & $13^2 = 169$ shown, but $19^2$ is *not* an option.